# save images to disk directory user chosen by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I got an object with image urls in it,and want to save them into the file directory user want. Like "save as " function ,pop a window to choose the directory in browser. And I'm so confused now .

Answer (score 0):

use [filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) it's most effective way.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you cannot directly save a file. You can cause the browser to prompt the user to save the file locally. You can refer this example.

http://www.muazkhan.com/2012/10/save-files-on-disk-using-javascript-or.html